# Triple integrals-finding the volume of cylinder.

Tags: surface-integrals

Find the volume of cylinder with base as the disk of unit radius in the $xy$ plane centered at $(1,1,0)$ and the top being the surface $$z=((x-1)^2+(y-1)^2)^{3/2}.$$
I just knew that this problem uses triple integral concept but dont know how to start. I just need someone to suggest an idea to start. I will proceed then. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The volume of the cylinder $C$ is given by the following triple integral
$$V=\iiint_{C}dzdydx=\iint_{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2\leq 1}((x-1)^2+(y-1)^2)^{3/2} dx dy\\
=\iint_{X^2+Y^2\leq 1}(X^2+Y^2)^{3/2} dX dY.$$
Now use the polar coordinates $X=\rho\cos(\theta)$, $Y=\rho\sin(\theta)$. Then $X^2+Y^2=\rho^2$ and $dX dY=\rho d\rho d\theta$ where $\rho$ is the [jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Example_2:_polar-Cartesian_transformation) of the transformation.
Thus we obtain
$$V=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\rho=0}^1 
\rho^{3} (\rho d\rho d\theta)=2\pi[\rho^5/5]_0^1=\frac{2\pi}{5}.$$

Comment: Can you please tell me how you arrived at the last step i.e. changing the eqn to polar form

Comment: @user371841 See my edited answer. Any further doubt?

Comment: thank you so much. Its clear.